# Moshi crashing at float values

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

I have this model class

```
data class RvRange(val low: Int?, val high: Int?)
```

My JSON response is

```
{"low":60799.999999999985,"high":168800.00000000003}
```

I want Moshi to automatically convert those float/Double values to Int but it crashes. 
is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not allow them to stay as Double and then convert to Int when you need to do something with them?

Comment: I don't want to do that, because It is a pretty big codebase and it would be a big change.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution would be creating your own adapter that internally converts `Double` to `Int`. Example:

```
object RvRangeAdapter : JsonAdapter<RvRange>() {

    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): RvRange? {
        reader.beginObject()

        var low: Int? = null
        var high: Int? = null
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            when (reader.nextName()) {
                "low" -> low = reader.nextDouble().roundToInt() // or any other kind of rounding logic
                "high" -> high = reader.nextDouble().roundToInt()
                else -> reader.skipValue() // let's ignore unknown fields
            }
        }
        reader.endObject()

        return RvRange(low, high)
    }

    @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: RvRange?) {
        writer.beginObject()
                .name("low").value(value?.low)
                .name("high").value(value?.high)
                .endObject()
    }
}
```

Once that's done, you'll need to register that adapter so that Moshi knows it can be used:

```
val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .add(RvRange::class.java, RvRangeAdapter)
        // any other configuration here
        .build()
```

When parsing the JSON you provided, the deserialised value will be:

```
RvRange(low=60800, high=168800)
```

Note that it doesn't really work with `null` values, so it would need some more tweaks if `null` is a valid value for "high" and/or "low".